# How can I add parameters to the end of all my state queries in UI Router Angular 1.6?

Tags: angularjs

In an Angular 1.6 application that has multiple states and utilizes UI-router, I would like to add parameters to the end of all state urls. 
 For example

```
   $stateProvider
    .state('something')
      url: '/'
    .state('something')
      url: '/something'
    .state('something')
      url: '/somethingElse
```

I would like to add three values at the end of all urls so the urls would look like: www.website.com/something/param1&param2&param3

Comment: This question is very basic, try to read UI-Router before asking anyone else...

Comment: I have read it; however, there is no explanation of where I can add the parameters without changing each state.

Comment: As soon as you add `/` anything on the URL isn't it going to try to resolve to a different state?

Comment: Oh yeah... I guess. I just need the variables there so I can later retrieve it. I guess it doesn't have to be in the URL. Could I use the params field then?

Comment: I don't think so because I believe you have to define the params on the URL as well as in a params: {} object. Are you locked into the format you've posted? If you could just use a normal querystring then you could use the `.search()` method of the `$location` service which wouldn't require you to do anything with your state definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your parameters in routing using `:` before the parameter name

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('something/:param1/:param2/:param3')
      url: '/'
    .state('something/:param1/:param2/:param3')
      url: '/something'
    .state('something/:param1/:param2/:param3')
      url: '/somethingElse
```

You can assign values to these parameters in URL as below:
 `URL: http://server.com/index.html#/something/1/2/3`

And you can retrieve them inside your controller using `$routeParams` as below

```
app.controller("somethingController", function ($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.param1 = $routeParams.param1;
  $scope.param2 = $routeParams.param2;
  $scope.param3 = $routeParams.param3;
});
```

You can also pass parameters directly without changing the routing, for example, 
`URL: http://server.com/index.html#/something?param1=AA&param2=BB&param3=CC&`

And retrieve them inside controller using `$route.current.params`

```
app.controller("somethingController", function ($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.param1 = $route.current.params.param1;
  $scope.param2 = $route.current.params.param2;
  $scope.param3 = $route.current.params.param3;
});
```